# ShowModal form that opens NSOpenPanel is force closed in Delphi Firemonkey OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, nsopenpanel

I am using the code @ http://jed-software.com/blog/?p=538 to open a dialog on OSX for selecting a folder

I'm creating a form using `Form2.ShowModal`, and on this form I am calling the above `SelectDirectory` function through a button. The form created with `ShowModal` is then instantly closed as soon as the `NSOpenPanel` is also closed... The forms `OnClose` event does not fire, and the `ModalResult` of the `Form2.ShowModal` call is `mrNone (0)`, so I haven't been able to find a way to stop this unwanted behaviour. Somehow the `LOpenDir.runModal;` result is forcing my `Form2` to close too

Any help would be fantastic, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `FRestartModal` flag inside the platformservice.

```
LDlgResult := LOpenDir.runModal;
RestartModal;
```

Unfortunately this is a bit nasty, because that flag is hidden in the TPlatformCocoa class in the implementation part of the unit. I don't like hacks using RTTI, but unfortunately I haven't found a better way. So here you go:

```pascal
procedure RestartModal;
//Hack: Set the FRestartModal flag in TPlatformCocoa
var
  Context: TRttiContext;
  RttiType: TRttiType;
  Field: TRttiField;
  FModalStack: TStack<TObject>;
  FPlatformService: TObject;
begin
  FPlatformService := TObject(TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXWindowService));  // trick for getting the MacOS Platformservice
  RttiType := Context.GetType(FPlatformService.ClassType);
  Field := RttiType.GetField('FModalStack');       // get private field using RTTI
  Assert(Field <> nil);
  FModalStack := PPointer(Field.GetValue(FPlatformService).GetReferenceToRawData)^;
  if (FModalStack <> nil) and (FModalStack.Count > 0) then
  begin
    Field := RttiType.GetField('FRestartModal');
    Field.SetValue(FPlatformService, True);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, tested and works great. I just saw your QC report about the issue

Comment: What unit is TStack in? Having issues getting this to work with XE8.

Comment: `TStack<>` is in Generics.Collections